# Where is verb transitivity listed in japanese dictionaries?

Tags: verbs, transitivity, dictionary

This may be a generic question. I wanted to see if a verb had some transitive use and thought a japanese-japanese dictionary would be more detailed than jisho.org, but I can't seem to find any mention to 他 or 自 neither in weblio.jp nor in goo.ne.jp, which are always my top 2 search results. Is this kind of information too specific for dictionaries?

Comment: This seems like a resource question since it depends on the dictionary and its own specific notations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Your question

> Where is verb transitivity listed in japanese dictionaries?

It depends.

Not your ideal answer, I'm sure, but it's true.

#### Some examples

My preferred monolingual Japanese dictionary is the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 (NKD), available in an abridged edition via [Kotobank](https://kotobank.jp/).  Due to a site "upgrade" a few years ago, actually *finding* the desired entry in the NKD can be a bit tricky.  But once you do, there's a great deal of useful detail.

[Here's a set of sample NKD entries](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A3%9F%E3%83%BB%E5%96%B0-2030835).  This includes the verb くう, くらう, くわせる, くらわす, くわす, くえる, くらわせる, and noun くい.

Let's look in more detail at the verb くう, the topmost one on that page.

> **く・う くふ【食・喰】**
> 〘他ワ五（ハ四）〙

Here's the top two lines.

- く・う

  - Tells us that the kanji spelling covers the く portion, and the う is [okurigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okurigana).
- くふ

  - This is the [historical kana spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_kana_orthography) ([歴史的【れきしてき】仮名遣【かなづか】い](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AD%B4%E5%8F%B2%E7%9A%84%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D%E9%81%A3)), used before the various spelling reforms of the late 19th and early-mid 20th centuries.  The historical spellings can sometimes give us better insight into word derivations and connections between words.
- 他ワ五

  - This tells us that this is a **他【た】**動詞【どうし】 or "transitive verb", that this conjugates based on the ワ set of kana (such as negative form く**わ**ない), and that this is a 五段【ごだん】 or "quintigrade" verb, with all five vowels appearing in the conjugated verb stems: くう・くい・くわ-・くえ・くおう).
- （ハ四）

  - This is more historical information about Classical Japanese (and deliberately archaic / hyper-formal forms).  We learn that, in the historical kana spellings, the verb conjugates based on the ハ set of kana, and that this is a 四段【よだん】 or "quadrigrade" verb, with four vowels appearing in the conjugated verb stems: くふ・くひ・くは-・くへ.
    ***Note:** Classical Japanese has no "-o" verb endings, because the suppositional / volitional in modern Japanese is actually a contraction of older form* -amu.  *So for modern くう, the volitional is くおう, and for Classical くふ, the volitional is くはむ.  The suppositional / volitional suffix in Classical is -む, and this attaches to the so-called 未然形【みぜんけい】 or "[irrealis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrealis_mood)" verb stem [basically, "the action of the verb hasn't happened yet"].*
    *In terms of phonological development, the *-amu* ending was originally pronounced as //amu//.  This changed to //ãu// with a nasal "a" sound, a bit like English "ow" with a stuffy nose.  This naturally evolved into //ɔː// like in English "aw", and then finally to the long //oː// like "oh" that we see in modern Japanese.*

Unfortunately, not all dictionaries provide this level of detail.  The corresponding Digital Daijisen entry [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%86-482263) doesn't specify transitivity at all:

> **く・う〔くふ〕【食う／×喰う】**
> ［動ワ五（ハ四）］

We are told that this is a **動【どう】**詞【し】 (verb), but not whether it's a 他動詞【たどうし】 (transitive verb) or a 自動詞【じどうし】 (intransitive verb).

To find out, we can dig around further.  The very first definition line in the Daijisen gives us this:

> **１** 食物をかんでのみ込む。食べる。「飯を―・う」

That bit at the end is a usage example.  Dictionary formatting often replaces the headword with a hyphen, so we know we can expand 「飯を―・う」 into 「飯を**食【く】**・う」.  And since we have the basic grammatical structure of `[NOUN]`を`[VERB]`, we can tell from both the definition and this usage example that 食【く】う is a transitive verb.

***Note:** We need the definition as well, since it is possible to have `[NOUN]`を`[VERB]` with intransitive verbs of motion, where the NOUN describes a place or time through which the action of the verb is happening, such as in 道【みち】を歩【ある】く ("to walk [up, down, along] the street").*

#### Conclusion

> Where is verb transitivity listed in japanese dictionaries?

When a dictionary specifies this information clearly, it should be right at the start of the entry, as we see above in the sample from the NKD.

If a dictionary doesn't specify this, try looking at the definitions and usage examples.